# MultiClass Text Classification using TensorFlow. output issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, text-classification, tf.keras

I'm checking the BBC news code from [towardsDataScience](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-lstm-using-tensorflow-2-0-d88627c10a35) multi-class problem, there are 5 labels and 6 prediction outputs, I tried giving it entertainment news

```
txt = ["last star wars .....  the film is much more dark  more emotional. it s much more of a tragedy."]
seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(txt)
padded = pad_sequences(seq, maxlen=max_length)
pred = model.predict(padded)
labels = ['sport', 'business', 'politics', 'tech', 'entertainment']
print(pred, labels[np.argmax(pred)])
```

and it returns

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-05bd09f68629> in <module>
      4 pred = model.predict(padded)
      5 labels = ['sport', 'business', 'politics', 'tech', 'entertainment']
----> 6 print(pred, labels[np.argmax(pred)])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I just added testlabel after entertainment label and output was!

```
   [[7.9564927e-07 7.9830606e-06 8.0213253e-04 3.8535093e-04 7.4164674e-02
  9.2463899e-01]] test label
```

model is here

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim,
                             input_length=max_length),
    # specify the number of convolutions that you want to learn, their size, and their activation function.
    # words will be grouped into the size of the filter in this case 5
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')
])
model.summary()
```

if i change the last dense to 5, it still give following error in training.

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 5 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5).  Label values: 3 2 1 5 4 4 2 5 5 3 1 1 3 1 4 1 5 3 2 5 3 3 4 3 5 2 3 2 4 5 3 5
     [[node loss_1/dense_3_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at <ipython-input-25-5196760ed1a6>:2) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_6926]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

Can somebody explain this to me? why is that? , and how to get same-outputs as number of labels?

Comment: What's the output of `print(pred.shape)`?

Comment: @thushv89   print(pred.shape) (1, 6)